# How to highlight the common rows from 2 separate dataframes in R?

Tags: r

I have 2 dataframes and I would like to highlight the common rows

```
library(openxlsx)

df = data.frame(Year = c(2018,2019,2020,2018,2019,2020,2018,2019,2020),
                Country = c("Germany","Germany","Germany", "Japan", "Japan", "Japan",  "Thailand", "Thailand", "Thailand"), 
                Count = c(17, 15, 60, 23, 25, 60, 50, 18, 31))


df2 = data.frame(Year = c(2018,2019,2020,2018,2019,2020,2018,2019,2020),
                Country = c("Germany","Germany","Germany", "Japan", "Japan", "Japan",  "Japan", "Thailand", "Thailand"), 
                Count = c(17, 100, 101, 102, 103, 60, 104, 18, 31))


wb = createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "Master")
writeDataTable(wb, "Master", df2, tableStyle = "TableStyleLight9")
yellow_style = createStyle(fgFill = "#FFFF00")
x = which(abs(df2$Count) == df$Count)
y = 1:which(colnames(df2) == "Count")
addStyle(wb, sheet = "Master", style = yellow_style, rows = x+1, col = y, gridExpand = TRUE)
saveWorkbook(wb, "Master.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Right now this set of codes work but it can only verify "Count" instead of the entire row.
If I want to find out the common "Count", it will work perfectly. But let's say I want to verify that the entire row is the same, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R approach. Use `paste` to create a composite of your columns, and identify which rows have same composite in other data frame.

```
x = which(do.call(paste, df2) %in% do.call(paste, df))
y = 1:ncol(df2)
```

Comment: Thanks! Works tremendously! Cheers mate

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the dataframes have the same dimensions (same number of rows and columns) you can simply compare them via `df == df2` and then check row-wise whether the result has only the value `TRUE` in each row:

```
library(tidyverse)

df = data.frame(Year = c(2018,2019,2020,2018,2019,2020,2018,2019,2020),
                Country = c("Germany","Germany","Germany", "Japan", "Japan", "Japan",  "Thailand", "Thailand", "Thailand"), 
                Count = c(17, 15, 60, 23, 25, 60, 50, 18, 31))


df2 = data.frame(Year = c(2018,2019,2020,2018,2019,2020,2018,2019,2020),
                Country = c("Germany","Germany","Germany", "Japan", "Japan", "Japan",  "Japan", "Thailand", "Thailand"), 
                Count = c(17, 100, 101, 102, 103, 60, 104, 18, 31))

eq_df <- as_tibble(df == df2)

eq_df <- eq_df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(rows_equal = (Year & Country & Count))
```

The resulting eq_df indicates in last column whether the respective row in `df` and `df2` are the same.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, my dataset may have different number of rows so this may not work. Cheers